# Cannot read property 'name' of undefined serverless esbuild

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-serverless, esbuild

Recently, I was going to change webpack with esbuild in aws serverless project. With webpack, everything was working fine. But, with esbuild, the following error is being shown:

```
× Unhandled exception in handler 'getNotification'.
× Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
× TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
at ...\.esbuild\.build\src\functions\api\index.js:21033:22
      at __decorateClass (...\.esbuild\.build\src\functions\api\index.js:32:24)
      at Object.<anonymous> (...\.esbuild\.build\src\functions\api\index.js:703945:1)
      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
      at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
      at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)
      at _tryRequireFile (...\node_modules\serverless-offline\src\lambda\handler-runner\in-process-runner\aws-lambda-ric\UserFunction.js:209:35)
```

Serverless.yaml:

```
plugins:
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin
  - serverless-offline-ssm
  - serverless-layers
  - serverless-scriptable-plugin
  - serverless-esbuild
  - serverless-offline
   ...

esbuild:
    bundle: true
    minify: false
```

My package versions:

- "serverless": "^3.22.0",
- "serverless-esbuild": "^1.32.8",
- "serverless-offline": "^9.3.1",
- "esbuild": "^0.15.7",